# Python statsmodels Granger Causality Test returning empty dictionary

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I am using the library `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests` to test the similarity between two time series. I know that both lists `a` and `b` are legitimate lists without any `None` or `nan` values, and they have the same size. The array that I call the causality test on does not have any problems either. I can't figure out why the call is only returning an empty dictionary.

```
grangercausalitytests([[a[i], b[i]] for i in range(0, len(a))], -1, verbose=True)
```

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maxlag should be a positive integer, not -1.

The loop to compute the results is never traversed.
http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html

```
maxlag : integer

    the Granger causality test results are calculated for all lags up to maxlag
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I first tried with a positive integer and I kept getting the error `maxlag should be at most -1`. I just restarted my server and it works now.

Comment: BTW: you can use `np.column_stack((a, b))` instead of your list loop. Maybe, you had observations in columns and two rows of variables, then the error message would say -1 because it is interpreted as nobs=2, AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the python statsmodel. So, for causality test you don't need to provide single element of a series at a time. Instead of that you should provide whole timeseries at a time. So, suppose you have two timeseries 'a', 'b' in 'T' than you can use following :

```
grangercausalitytests(np.column_stack((T['a'][1:],T['b'][1:])), 10)
```